# Sending a message after a ban/kick command

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm setting up a discord bot, and I want to have the bot send a confirmation or error message after the commands "ban" and "kick", can anyone help?

I have tried creating another separate command with the same arguments, except just having it send the expected message.

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready!')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(ctx, member):
    print(f'{member} has joined {ctx.guild.name}.')

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(ctx, member):
    print(f'{member} has left {ctx.guild.name}.')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name="Member")
    await client.add_roles(member, role)

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Pong! :ping_pong: **{round(client.latency * 1000)}ms** ')

@client.command()
async def purge(ctx, amount):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    await ctx.send(f'{member.display_name} has been kicked.')

@client.command()
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'{member.display_name} has been kicked.'')

@client.command()
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'The Ban Hammer has Spoken! {member.display_name} has been banned!')

@client.command()
async def pardon(ctx, *, member):
    banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
    member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#')

    for ban_entry in banned_users:
        user = ban_entry.banned_users

        if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
            await ctx.send(f'Unbanned {member.display_name}')
```

In actuality, I think it would be great, because they clash with each other and probably will send a message, but it went wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand.. you know that you can have multiple lines in function right? So for example in ban function you can have first line `await member.ban(reason=reason)` and second line `await ctx.send(f'{member.display_name} has been banned!')`

Comment: I have tried such code, the bot program does not even start now.

Comment: Edit your post so we can see the problem.

Comment: Do not redefine functions. Instead of defining `ban()` twice, define it once and have it call both `await member.ban()` and `await ctx.send(...)`

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the kick command delete that last '. And also do `{member.name}` or `{member}`